# Send email only when first two columns are filled in

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have this script working so that when the last row is edited it sends an email with the contents of the first two columns from that row. My issue is that if info is entered into any column of the last row then a blank email gets sent. I've tried a combination of `if` statements to get the result I want but either end up with the script working as it currently is, or not working at all.

```
// This function grabs the last row of a inventory sheet and sends the updated range to a specified recipient using a onEdit trigger
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // If edit is not made on "Iventory" sheet then function does not proceed
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Inventory") return;
  // Get last row of sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Get range of last row
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = lastCell.getValues();
  //empty string
  var message =""
  //Loop through each row and form CSV data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    message = message + row[0] + "-" +row[1] + "\n";  
  }
  // Send one email with all the rows
  var subject = "Inventory update"; 
  MailApp.sendEmail("test@test.com", subject, message);
}
```

Comment: I notice you don't use the [`event object`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that is included when you use triggers to activate functions (i.e. the `e` in `function sendEmails(e) {` gets event data). From the event object, you will be able to determine exactly which cell was edited - `e.range` - by checking its sheet (`e.range.getSheet()`), row (`e.range.getRow()`), and column (`e.range.getColumn()`). With this knowledge, you should be able to appropriately guard your notification email code.

Comment: @tehhowch I was curious if there was a way to edit the event object. Thanks for the tip I should be able to get the script to behave as intended now. Thanks again!

Comment: You can, but should you? Its purpose is to let you know the details of what previously happened (to invoke the function's execution, and provide it the context it needs to run as intended). You can just as easily create your own objects (`var mine = {"name": "My Object", "myArray": ["my array element 1", "my array element 2", ... ], .... }`) that serve whatever purpose you need them for.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var send=true;
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
    var row = data[i];
    message = message + row[0] + "-" +row[1] + "\n";  
  if(!row[0] || !row[1]){
    send=false;
    break;
  }
}
  // Send one email with all the rows
  var subject = "Inventory update"; 
if(send){
  MailApp.sendEmail("test@test.com", subject, message);
}
```